# What is the natural way to make the set of all holomorphic functions into a Banach space?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $E$ and $F$ be locally convex spaces, and $U \subseteq E$ an open subset. Let $\mathcal H(U; F )$
denote the vector space of all holomorphic mappings $f : U \to F$ . When $F = \mathbb C$,
we write $\mathcal H(U)$ instead of $\mathcal H(U; F )$,

> What is the natural way to make the set of all holomorphic functions into a Banach space?

If $f$ is assumed to be bounded, We endow $\mathcal H(U)$ with the norm $\lVert f\rVert:=\sup_{z\in U}|f(z)|$, which is well-defined since $f$ is bounded.

Now in  general case,I want to know what norm would be suitable in order to make it complete .

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what type of convergence you are interested in.

Comment: I want to know is there  any norm to make $\mathcal H(U)$complete

Answer (score 1):

Not a very useful one: if $E=\mathbb{C}$, if we equip $\mathcal{H}(U)$ with its natural topology (i.e. the compact open topology), we have [Montel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem),
which implies that a set is compat in $\mathcal{H}(U)$ iff it is closed and bounded. Since clearly $\mathcal{H}(U)$ is an infinite dimensional vector space (it contains the polynomials), it cannot be a Banach space (it is actually an example of a [Montel space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel_space))

On the other hand, there is a norm which makes it a complete banach space, since
$\mathcal{H}(U)$ has dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$ and it is thus isomorphic (as a vector space) to a Banach space $B$ of the same dimension. Defining $||v||_{\mathcal{H}(U)}:=||f(v)||_B$ gives $\mathcal{H}(U)$ a Banach space structure